# malloc() in C returns populated memory

Tags: c, string, malloc, heap-memory

`char *string = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * sz);`

code right before this->`void insert_word(word *root, char string1[], int linenumber) { int sz=strlen(string1)<=MAX_WORD_LENGTH?strlen(string1):MAX_WORD_LENGTH;` *Code block 3 has the entire context*

Sometimes malloc() returns a populated memory location while using it.

What bothers me is that this is not random.
(This program consists of taking words from a file and passing them to this function. For THE SAME WORD, the function behaviour(in particular that of malloc()) is different.

For the inputs
`string1=0x7fffffffdf10 "lol"`  root=[BST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yIl8.png), sz gets a value of `3`

The value allocated to `string` by malloc() is `0x55555555c510 "\340\305UUUU"` Why is malloc not pointing to an empty memory location? (This is not random behaviour, it is predictable and repeatable)
Furthermore,this loop runs an infinite amount of time for some reason

```
while(strcmp(string1,string)!=0)
    {
        free(string);
        string=NULL;
        string = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * sz);
        strncpy(string,string1,sz);
    }
```

MORE RELAVANT CODE

1. `#define MAX_WORD_LENGTH 20`
2. Definition of the structures

   ````
   typedef struct linkedList
       {
           int number;
           struct linkedList *next;
       }list;
       typedef struct word_with_count
       {
           char* string;
           list *linenumbers;
           struct word_with_count *left;
           struct word_with_count *right;
       }word;```
   ````

[3] ) The function

```
void insert_word(word *root, char string1[], int linenumber) {
    int sz=strlen(string1)<=MAX_WORD_LENGTH?strlen(string1):MAX_WORD_LENGTH;
    char *string = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * sz);
    strncpy(string,string1,sz);
    if (root==NULL) {
        return;
    } else if (strcmp(string, root->string) < 0) {
        if (root->left == NULL) {
            root->left = createword(string, linenumber);
        } else {
            insert_word(root->left, string, linenumber);
        }
    } else if (strcmp(string, root->string) > 0) {
        if (root->right == NULL) {
            root->right = createword(string, linenumber);
        } else {
            insert_word(root->right, string, linenumber);
        }
    } else {
        append_list(linenumber, root->linenumbers);
    }
    free(string);
}
```

4. main() which calls this function

```
int main() {
    char path[MAX_PATH_LENGTH];
    FILE *fp;
    fgets(path, MAX_PATH_LENGTH, stdin);

    if (strlen(path) > 0 && path[strlen(path) - 1] == '\n')
        path[strlen(path) - 1] = '\0';
    
    fp = fopen(path, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("File not found\n");
        return 0;
    }
    char ch;
    int line_count = 1;
    char current_word[MAX_WORD_LENGTH] = "";

    word *root = NULL;
    while (!feof(fp)) {
        ch = fgetc(fp);
        //printf("%c", ch);

        if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z' || ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') {
            if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z')
                ch = ch - 'A' + 'a';

            strncat(current_word, &ch, 1);
        } else if (ch == '-') {
            continue;
        } else {
            if (strlen(current_word) > 2) {
                if (root == NULL) {
                    root = createword(current_word, line_count);
                } else {
                    insert_word(root, current_word, line_count);
                }
            }
            memset(current_word, 0, sizeof(current_word));
            if (ch == '\n') {
                line_count++;
            }
        }
    }
    if (strlen(current_word) > 2) {
        if (root == NULL) {
            root = createword(current_word, line_count);
        } else {
            insert_word(root, current_word, line_count);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    // print_tree(root);
    //printf("\n");
    //print_tree(root);
    int status=delete_low_ocurrence(root, NULL, 3);
    if (status == -1)root = NULL;
    print_tree(root);
    freetree(root);
    return 0;
}
```

5)Auxilary function used by this function

```
word* createword(char string[], int linenumber)
{
    word *newword = (word*)malloc(sizeof(word));
    int sz=strlen(string)<=MAX_WORD_LENGTH?strlen(string):MAX_WORD_LENGTH;
    newword->string = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*sz);
    strncpy(newword->string, string,sz);
    newword->linenumbers = (list*)malloc(sizeof(list));
    newword->linenumbers->number = linenumber;
    newword->linenumbers->next = NULL;
    newword->left = NULL;
    newword->right = NULL;
    return newword;
}
```

6. Textfile given as input

```
much2f
much3f
lol
lol
lol
qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmqwertyuiop
qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmqwertyuiop
qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmqwertyuiop
qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmqwertyuiop
```

Comment: There is no such thing as empty memory. Think about a byte as eight switches that can be flipped up or down, like light switches. If the switches are all down, that encodes 0, if they are all up, that is 255. What would it mean for these switches to be “empty”? The switches are never gone or invisible. They are always there, each one in an up or down position. There is no empty memory.

Answer (score 2):

> Why is malloc not pointing to an empty memory location?

Because it can.  The content of the allocated memory via `malloc()` is not specified.

If code needs zeroed out memory, see `calloc()`.

---

**Bad code**

`strncpy(string,string1,sz)` does not result in `string` being a *string* as it may lack null character termination.  The following `(strcmp(string...` is then *undefined behavior*.  Instead, do not use `strncpy()`, use `strcpy()` and make certain the prior allocation has enough room for the terminating *null character*.

```
strncpy(string,string1,sz);
...
} else if (strcmp(string, root->string) < 0) { // bad
```

Repaired code

```
word* createword(const char string[], int linenumber) {
  word *newword = calloc(1, sizeof *newword);
  size_t length = strlen(string);
  if (length > MAX_WORD_LENGTH) {
    length = MAX_WORD_LENGTH;
  }
  char *s = malloc(length + 1); // Include room for the \0
  list *linenumbers = calloc(1, sizeof *linenumbers);
  // Test allocation success
  if (newword == NULL || s == NULL || linenumbers == NULL) {
    free(newword);
    free(s);
    free(linenumbers);
    return NULL;
  }
  memcpy(s, string, length);  // Only copy the first 'length' characters.
  s[length] = 0;
  newword->string = s;
  newword->linenumbers = linenumbers;
  newword->linenumbers->number = linenumber;
  newword->linenumbers->next = NULL;
  newword->left = NULL;
  newword->right = NULL;
  return newword;
}
```

---

**[Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/2410359)**

`feof(fp)` improperly used here.  `fgetc()` returns 257 different values.  Do not use `char ch`.

```
//char ch;
//...
//while (!feof(fp)) {
//    ch = fgetc(fp);

int ch;
...
while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {;
```

Comment: In other words, you still have to initialize, just as you always do in C.  There are a few exceptions like some local variables, but generally speaking, get into the habit of always initializing your variables.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Always initializing is reasonable axiom for learners.  Yet on deeper review, it looks like OP is not  accounting for space for a _null character_.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite normal behaviour. 'malloc' just does the memory allocation, it makes no commitment on what's already in that memory location. What you probably need is 'calloc', which clears the memory and then allocates it to your program.